# ZFS Tunings for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance-tuning, ubuntu, timescaledb

What are the recommended ZFS tunings for PostgreSQL 11 (with TimescaleDB 1.6 extension) running on striped mirrored vdevs of SATA3 SSDs?

I am considering:

- `ashift=12`
- `atime=off`
- `relatime=on` (or off?)

But am unsure about the following:

- `xattr=sa`
- `logbias=throughput`
- `redundant_metadata=most`

Data compression is pretty important, so I am thinking of keeping the default setting of `recordsize=128K` instead of changing it to `8K` which will likely cause data compression to be much less effective.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You should always use `ashift=12` today unless you have an overwhelmingly good reason not to.

`relatime=off` might save you a vanishingly small amount. Don't expect it to be measurable.

`xattr=sa` is important if you use extended attributes (e.g. SELinux) and you have a lot of tables and file opening/closing operations.

`logbias=throughput` should reduce your disk I/O volume, and it will help with SSD storage where there is no huge disconnect between bandwidth and latency like there is on spinning media.

`recordsize=8k` will ensure you don't have any RMW overheads. You'll have to decide whether the extra compression ratio achievable with larger `recordsize` is a net victory in your use case.

You may find [the slides from a lecture I gave](https://www.slideshare.net/GordanBobic/mysql-on-zfs) on the subject useful.